# Can I get the results of a stored procedure into a cursor within another stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I'm trying to put the results of a stored procedure into a cursor to use within the current procedure. I've added my code below but I'm not sure if this is possible or if my syntax is correct?

```
DECLARE cursorIDList CURSOR FOR
    EXEC spGetUserIDs
OPEN cursorIDList

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorIDList INTO @ID
```

I receive the following error: Incorrect syntax near 'EXEC'. Expecting SELECT, '(' or WITH.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, I get an error: Incorrect syntax near 'EXEC'. Expecting SELECT, '(' or WITH.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT)
INSERT INTO @t
EXEC spGetUserIDs

DECLARE cursorIDList CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM @t
OPEN cursorIDList

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorIDList INTO @ID
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks. If the sp returns more than 1 column can they be matched in the newly declared table? Thanks again

Comment: No. You need to create the table with as many columns as procedure retunrs

Comment: Before SP returns result you have to already have a table variable with matching columns, you have to know data types of the columns in a data set returned by the SP and according to that create them in a table variable before the procedure call.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion very interesting approach would be to use cursor as parameter (although if you not going to update table i don't think its better choice):

```
create Table dbo.MyTable
(
    i int 
);
Insert Into dbo.MyTable (i) values (1)
Insert Into dbo.MyTable (i) values (2)
Insert Into dbo.MyTable (i) values (3)
Insert Into dbo.MyTable (i) values (4)
Go
Set NoCount ON;
Go
Create Proc dbo.myProc 
(
    @someValue int,
    @cur Cursor Varying Output
)
As
Begin 
    declare @x int;

    Set @cur = Cursor for
        Select i From dbo.MyTable
        Where i < @someValue;

    open @cur
End
Go
-- Use of proc
declare @cur cursor;
declare @x int;
Exec dbo.myProc 3, @cur output


fetch next from @cur into @x
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    print 'value: ' + cast(@x as varchar)
    fetch next from @cur into @x
end

close @cur;
Deallocate @cur;

Go
--Cleanup
Drop Proc dbo.myProc 
Drop Table dbo.MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of cursor in SQL-Server is:

```
DECLARE cursor_name [ INSENSITIVE ] [ SCROLL ] CURSOR FOR select_statement
```

After `FOR` you must write a `SELECT`.

For more info see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms180169.aspx