# Can a stored procedure be used in a cursor?

Tags: sql, sybase, cursors

Often cursors are created using SQL code, such as:

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT SIN(A),COS(A)
FROM FGR_db_Database..tb_Angles
WHERE A BETWEEN 0 AND 360`

If the code already exists as a procedure, or more likely a much more complicated bit of code, could the procedure be used instead? For example:

`DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR
FOR EXEC sp_PR_ProcedureName @l_Angle`

I have tried but so far unsuccessfully and didn't know if it was at all possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked out this page yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342306/can-i-get-the-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-cursor-within-another-stored

Comment: I hadn't actually, no. However, they are on SQL Server 2008 and I'm on Sybase Transact SQL so I think I might not be able to whip off any of the stunts, especially since it looks slightly foreign to me... :o\

Comment: Sybase was a company, not  a database.  Can you be more specific about which product you are using(ASE, IQ, SQL Anywhere, etc), it can make a difference in syntax.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure namewise but I've always known it as Sybase Transact SQL 12.7 running on a Unix server. Any better?

Comment: Not really.  Transact SQL is just the language name (which MS also uses in SQL Server).  It's likely you are running either IQ (which had a 12.7 release), or ASE (which did not have a 12.7 release).  Execute the command `select @@version` and that will tell you the software and version you are running.

Comment: I had a horrid feeling about that, but much appreciated anyway. Seems there is a way around it (-ish!) with the good ol' temporary table. It's not perfect but it works.