# Stored proc is assigning incorrect value to bit variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to assign theresult of a stored procedure to a variable within another stored proc. so the code in looks a bit like this:

```
 DECLARE @val1  bit

 DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
(
    status bit
);

  INSERT @tempTable 
  EXEC @val1 = dbo.pr2
```

Now the thing is I know that calling dbo.pr2 returns a value of 1. However when I run the calling stored procedure it always assigns a value of 0 to the variable @val1.

Am I doing something incorrectly here?

(Note: dbo.pr2 returns a SELECT statement which is always just a single bit. I cannot alter this stored procedure. The temp table is used in the above to suppress the result of this query being passed up when the calling stored procedure is executed)

Comment: Use Output parameter in your `SP`

Comment: This was explained in your previous question.  A stored procedures *return* value is what is specified by a `RETURN` statement, which has to be an integer.  *Nothing else* is it's "return value".  It cannot *return* a `SELECT` statement, that's an entirely different type of procedure output, that SQL can only consume with the `INSTERT .. EXEC..` statement.

Comment: An *output parameter* is a third type of output that a stored procedure can have.  It's the easiest form for other SQL statements to consume, so you may want to use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The result set is not the return value of a stored procedure - the two are very different concepts. So whatever you return in a `select` will not be returned as the return value of the procedure.

There's already a question handling getting the result set of a stored procedure - [Can I get the results of a stored procedure into a cursor within another stored procedure in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342306/can-i-get-the-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-cursor-within-another-stored)

Far from ideal, but...